# How to change Android checkbox style

Tags: android, checkbox, styles

I need a little help to customize checkbox's look.
My xml file is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:text="@string/preferances_title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textSize="26sp" />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/soundCheckBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:text="@string/soundEnabled"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

it looks like this

[image]

I want my checkbox look like this(with title and description)

[image]

how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well since (from what i understand) you want to create a preference screen.

I suggest you use a PreferenceFragment or PreferenceActivity which inflates its layout
from an xml.

There are many examples on the internet just search : *preference screen tutorial*

I believe that the second image uses a CheckBoxPreference,
So if you want to create something like the second image you can use this in your xml
which will have the exact same view.

```
<CheckBoxPreference
            android:defaultValue="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/image"
            android:key="preference_key"
            android:summary="@string/preference_summary"
            android:title="@string/preference_title" />
```

*Note that CheckBoxPreference cannot be used on all layouts but only in a PreferenceActivity*

Else if you want to create something like this but without a preference you can use a
**CheckedTextView** which has a checkbox to the right but no subtitle which you will need to add as a textview in your layout.

Comment: The official documentation for a settings screen in Android is here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `RelativeLayout` to get the layout in the second image:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="Lock screen notifications"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Show notifications on lock screen" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```